# What's a good advanced photo guide for the iphone5s (ios7 of course)?

Tags: ios, photos, camera, iphone

I see a lot of guides "do you know you can use the volume control to take pics?" I need something "this is how you lock focus and get a 2 stop reduction in light from the flash"

Is there anything like this available?

And yes, I have used Google to look for myself, and I typically find "How to use your new iPhone guides" that have way too much emphasis on iPhoto and iCloud and not enough on shooting. I'm looking more for "you know your way around an SLR, these are the cool things you can do with an iPhone". E.g. this is how you focus, this is how you do 2 stop over-exposure compensation, this is how you do 2 stop under flash exposure (useful for outdoor sunny days). How do you do "bulb" exposures?

So, instead of Google, i'm asking if anyone has any personal encounter with such a guide, since most of the guides you will find on Google are (by nature) for people with lower requirements.

And if the flexibility comes from some feature I'm missing in in the stock app, yay for me. But there are two possibilities if its not:

- An app was written and someone has a recommendation
- There are no API
  hooks for what I want and therefore there never can be an app that
  does the above

Comment: you mean, some apps?

Comment: Hi, this question is a little bit too broad. I suggest you edit again. But ask for known capabilities of the camera of the iPhone 5s. And any apps that use any of them that is fully featured and fully documented in the use of those features.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Googling yet?
Padam, [here's](http://www.macworld.com/article/2048867/get-to-know-ios-7-camera-and-photos.html) the first option for you to check out, explaining all features.

Comment: Thanks, but of course I tried Google… But all the guides are for beginners and deal with features I already know. I'm looking for more advanced, prosumer photographer level tips. Thanks for the answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

No longer iOS 7, but I did fine [iPhone Photo School](http://iphonephotographyschool.com/) which looks about the level I wanted.